# Is there a site where you can run mathematica without having to download anything?

Tags: slideshows

I made a project in mathematica, and I have to present it in front of a couple of layman in two days, but I have to use school laptops and for some stupid reason I am not allowed to download anything on that laptop.

So my question is: Is there a site which can run my code so I can show what I've made using mathematica?

Comment: Any alternative solutions are also appreciated if the answer to this question is "no"

Comment: It depends on what your code depends on. http://www.mathics.org/ is the closest but I doubt you code will work out of the box. Probably buying a Raspberry-Pi with Wolfram-10 on it will solve your problem if it's not computationally intensive.

Comment: I believe you will need access to an instance of *webMathematica*.  Such services can be purchased.  Also, although I haven't used it in years http://www.mathematica-users.org/ used to provide limited *webMathematica* access via a Wiki interface; it *might* just be enough to get you through.

Comment: How about making a movie using a free tool like [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries good point - in fact I have switched to preparing mp4 screencasts (here with Debut Video Capture) rather than live demos because most of the time I need to use Powerpoint or machines w/o *Mathematica*.

Comment: Unfortunately, *Mathematica* Online is not live yet. You could try to contact WRI for a beta account. Perhaps posting at community.wolfram.com can help you there.

Comment: wolframcloud.com, though it's no help to you now sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is!
Wolfram recently launched an online version of mathematica in various forms.
You can register for the "programming cloud" and show them a full mathematica notebook online.

With the free account you'll be missing a few IO abilities (no databases, limited file IO iirc). This should be more than enough to demonstrate your work.

https://www.wolframcloud.com